# Join 2 table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what I have in the tables

User table

```
ID   Name
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
5    e
6    f
```

Friend table

```
UID   FID  Fname
1      2     b
1      3     c
1      6     f
```

Now I do the join of the tables, i want to see the records when id =6 to show

```
ID   Name
1    a
2    b
3    c
4    d
5    e
```

but when i run for id = 1

I want to see just

```
ID   Name
4    d
5    e
```

Tried to see if any of the suggestion from stackoverflow would work, but did not find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary that you should always use `joins`.

Just try this

**EDIT**

```
select ID, Name from user where ID not in (select FID from friend where UID = 1) and ID != 1
```

I'm getting the result perfectly for both `id = 1` and `id = 6`

[image: id = 1]

[image: id = 6]

Comment: the syntax did not work, getting all the records from user table

Comment: no error, but wrong set of data, it brought in matching records also.

Comment: can you post what set of data you got after running this query

Comment: ID   Name
2    b
3    c
4    d
5    e
6    f

Comment: you are fetching for `id=1` or `id=6`

Comment: look my answer i have attached two picture it is working for me

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, followed step by step and looked at each variable and now it works. Thanks a lot for taking the time and being patiet with me.